# Python sockets protocols have the same value

Tags: linux, networking, python, sockets, protocol

So i am reading this book and in chapter about packet sniffing i uses this

`s = socket.socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, sock.htons(0x0800))`

I looked up to which protocol has the value 8 since  htons(0x0800)

In the list of ip protocols 8 is EGP which i did not get why we would use this protocol and looked for more examples and got more confused one example used 0x0003 which is 3 when i looked into it more 3 is the value for GGP protocol and eth_p_all protocol at the same time.

My questions are:

1.Some protocol values seems to be same in the links i provided does socket use protocols based on family or is there something i am not getting?

2.i understand raw sockets and usage of eth_p_all but i do not understand how it diffets from ggp protocol (in regards of value they both are 3)

I found some questions regarding the issue but answers doesent explain what is the difference rather what should be used.

Sorry if i don't make sense i am very confused.

Just a note first i thought it was based on family what protocols were useb but then i found people using af_inet with eth_p_all so there goes that and i found some examples using ntohs(0x0003) this value is somewhere around 700 which got me more confused (i belive there was an error with that example but i am not sure)

Links:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers?wprov=sfla1

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/if_ether.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two different kinds of raw sockets.

With `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW)` you are working at IP layer and you always send/receive IPv4 packets with custom payload. The "protocol" sets the protocol field of the IPv4 header (e.g. 3 for "GGP" or 6 for "UDP").

With `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW/DGRAM)` you are working at layer 2 and you send/receive Ethernet frames. The "protocol" sets the protocol field in the Ethernet header, aka the "ethertype" (e.g. 0x0800 for "IPv4" or 0x0806 for "ARP" or 0x8137 for "Netware IPX").

The file /etc/protocols only lists values found in the IP header – it does not list Ethernet frame types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.